# Bibliography as chapter (in ToC, fancyhdr) in book document class

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, fancyhdr, subfiles

I want my bibliography to be treated as a chapter with class `book`, but right now it's being treated as a section of the previous chapter (the LE header is of the previous chapter, and it's not bolded / doesn't have the correct spacing in the ToC). None of the fixes I've found online work, perhaps because I have some other conflicting command? Here's a minimal working example:

in `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parindent{0.5in}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\nocite}{\ifx\@onlypreamble\document}{\iftrue}{}{}
\makeatother


\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}% clears all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables


\chapter{Chapter1}
\subfile{Chapter1.tex}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{main.bib}

\end{document}
```

in `Chapter1.tex`:

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

Example \cite{CentralDogma}.

\end{document}
```

in `main.bib`:

```
@article{CentralDogma,
  doi = {10.1038/227561a0},
  year  = {1970},
  publisher = {Springer Nature},
  volume = {227},
  number = {5258},
  pages = {561--563},
  author = {Francis Crick},
  title = {Central Dogma of Molecular Biology},
  journal = {Nature}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either load package apacite with option `nosectionbib`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}% <- option nosectionbib
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section 1}
\cite{CentralDogma}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{main}
\end{document}
```

or put the bibliography in back matter:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{apacite}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section 1}
\cite{CentralDogma}
\backmatter% <- added
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{main}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Loading apacite with [nosectionbib] did the trick and is so simple and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I reduced your given code to be more minimal:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,openany]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\nocite}{\ifx\@onlypreamble\document}{\iftrue}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section 1}

\cite{CentralDogma}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{main} % bibliography file without extention .bib!

\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image: resulting pdf]

In class `boob.cls`  the environment is defined. We can now redefine it with the code (see line two, where we use `\chapter*` as you wish):

```
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
 {\chapter*{\bibname}% <============================================
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
  \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
       {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
        \leftmargin\labelwidth
        \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
        \@openbib@code
        \usecounter{enumiv}%
        \let\p@enumiv\@empty
        \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty4000
  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.\@m}
 {\def\@noitemerr
   {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist}
```

With the complete code

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,openany]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\nocite}{\ifx\@onlypreamble\document}{\iftrue}{}{}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\chapter*{\bibname}% <==============================================
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section 1}

\cite{CentralDogma}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{main} % bibliography file without extention .bib! <===========

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: new pdf]